# Vaadin Checkbox -- Add a newline on caption

Tags: java, checkbox, newline, vaadin

I am trying to set the caption of a checkbox and i want to break at a certain point in the string to create a new line without waiting for the word wrap:

When i added the simple `\n` character to caption string it did not work.

```
        private CheckBox completeCheckbox;
completeCheckbox.setCaption("why wont this\n break");
```

Comment: Can't you convert new line characters to <br/> and then make the checkbox not escape special HTML characters? (Something like completeCheckBox.setCaptionAsHtml("this should<br/>break"); I don't know this framework, but they should have some option like that.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and the simple solution for this was to call "setCaptionAsHtml(true)" on the CheckBox instance and to set the caption using HTML code.

```
private CheckBox completeCheckbox = createMyCheckboxSomehowFunction();
completeCheckbox.setCaptionAsHtml(true);
completeCheckbox.setCaption("why wont this<br/>break");
```

The above code snippet should do what you want. At least it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

i think the solution is to use an [Option Group](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler#OptionGroupHtmlItems)

I just read that [here](https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/search?_19_redirect=https://vaadin.com/forum?p_p_id=19&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=row-1&p_p_col_pos=1&p_p_col_count=2&_19_breadcrumbsCategoryId=0&_19_breadcrumbsMessageId=0&_19_searchCategoryId=0&_19_threadId=0&_19_keywords=line%20break%20checkbox&_19_itemsPerPage=20&_19_page=1&_19_itemsPerPage=20&_19_page=1)

Comment: I have tried using an option group but cant figure out how to exactly use it. When following the vaadin sampler it doesn't provide a single checkbox style. How do i create one option in an option group